# comparing cards from an array created with a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

First of all I am pretty new to Javascript and programming in general. So don't be offended if this is a stupid question. I am creating a browser game of Texas Hold'em and first of all I am starting of creating an array of cards in a for-loop then shuffling with Math.random that results in something like [C5,H4,S3,..]
and so on. My question is how do I best compare these cards. My worst fear is the flush and straight-flush.

Comment: Code. whathaveyoutried

Comment: Sort. Most of hands should be easy to check with appropriate order.

Comment: Please show us your actual code.  And, describe what you want do do with "compare these cards"?  Are you trying to evaluate the strength of a poker hand?

Comment: i think the code is too long to post but essentially i have 2 different arrays playercards and tablecards and @jfriend00 indeed i want to evaluate the strength of a poker hand. I m guessing the best way for evaluating the suits would be substring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DamirDžilić - without any real code to comment on, we can only give conceptual advice.  You're going to have to just compare each hand against all possible poker hands, starting with the highest rated hand down to a single pair.

I'd personally suggest that each card be an object:

```
var card = {suit: "S", value: 9};
```

Then, a hand would be an array of card objects.

You can then look at suit and card value separately.  It would be easier if card values where 2 through 14 and you convert to J, Q, K, A only for display.

Then, each possible poker hand (pair, three of a kind, four of a kind, flush, straight, etc...) would get a score in order of their value in poker (pair = 1, two pair = 2, three of a kind = 3, straight = 4, flush = 5, full house = 6, straight flush = 7, four of a kind = 8, straight flush = 9).

Then, I'd suggest you give each type of hand a score which consist of 10000*hand value + 100*top card in hand + value of kicker.  So, a pair of 8's with a K kicker would be worth:

```
(2*10000) + (8*100) + 13 = 20,813
```

And, three 2's with an A kicker would be:

```
(3*10000) + (2*100) + 14 = 30,214
```

With this type of scoring system, the hand value always dominates, then the top card that's part of the scoring piece of the hand (e.g. 3 queens beats 3 eights), then the kicker breaks any ties.

It would be up to you to write the code for figuring out what kind of hand you have, but basically you have to examine for straights, flushes and how many common cards you have.  I'd probably look for pairs first and only if there are no pairs do you look for straights or flushes and I'd make a function to look for each.

Comment: thank you very much that was exactly what i was looking for as i said i am new to programming and should have done more research before starting. But i think you nailed it and i will have to go back to the top of the script and change my array of strings to objects.

Comment: @DamirDžilić - it's a bad idea to put multiline code in comments.  It is unreadable.  If you need to post additional code, use the Edit feature and add it to the end of your question.  In this particular case, I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @DamirDžilić - are you aware of how StackOverflow works?  If someone answers your question, you should indicate a "best answer" by checking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  This indicates to others reading your question that this answer worked for you.  It also rewards the person who provided the answer with reputation points and earns you some reputation points for following the proper procedure on StackOverflow.  Later, when you've earned more reputation points, you can also upvote any answer that seems helpful, even on questions that aren't your own.